# R: unable to use select() on variables in dataframe from PDB

Tags: r, protein-database

I have been using R but new to PDB files for protein structure. I hope to modify values in PDB files as if they are common dataframe.

Here's what I did:

```
library(bio3d)
library(tidyverse)

pdb <- read.pdb("7nhx")
atom <- as.data.frame(pdb$atom)
```

but then I cannot do something like

```
pb1_atom <- atom %>% 
  select(atom$chain == "B")
```

Is this because of the nature of PDB files? Is there any way to make the "atom" section a normal dataframe and convert it back after making some modifications? Thank you!

Comment: The error I got is

Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
i It must be numeric or character.

Comment: You might be mixing up `select` and `filter`.  Probably want something like `atom %>% filter(chain == "B")`.